# How to align buttons and text views automatically for all different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

[image]I have built a BMI Calculator app. My text views, edit text, and buttons align differently in different screen sizes. How to align it so that it fits all screens?

I've already tried the previous answers in StackOverflow but so of the properties are removed in a new version of the android studio and also read google documentation but couldn't understand...Sorry!

My XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#5864"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="161dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="161dp"
        android:text="@string/bmi_calculator"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.436"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:ems="10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:hint="@string/enter_height"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userHeight"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="106dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:hint="@string/enter_weight"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userBMI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/your_bmi_will_be_displayed_here"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userWeight"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="@string/calculate_bmi"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userBMI"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm learning android on my own, a little help, please.
I've added the images showing how my app looks in two different screen size.

[image]

Comment: what do you really wants for alignements ?

Comment: How to align all the elements correctly in different screen sizes. I've added images, please see. @SebastienRieu

Comment: what elements do you wants to be at the bottom, at the top etc. ?

Comment: elements are placed correctly but I want to display them in same manner for all screen sizes, in the first image(with back button) it is displayed correctly but in second image the alignment goes for a toss (Calculate BMI button moved almost to center compare to the first image). I want to avoid that. So how to set a layout file so that all elements displayed in a similar manner in all screen sizes. @SebastienRieu

Comment: I would suggest that you wrap your views in a vertical linear layout that has it's height equal to match parent, set each subview's view height to 0 and add a view weight to each of them, in order to match your needs. If you still want to use Constraint Layout then extract the margin top for each element in a dimen file and add multiple values, considering screen density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create "chain" --> constraint all bottoms of your component to the top of the element at it bottom using app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#5864">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bmi_calculator"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userHeight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_height"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userWeight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_weight"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/userBMI"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userHeight" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userBMI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/your_bmi_will_be_displayed_here"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userWeight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="@string/calculate_bmi"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userBMI" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a ton bro, solved my problem. @SebastienRieu